# How to fill empty javascript array with search results from a php form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Empty Array:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foodList=[];
</script>
```

**php Form:**

```
<form id="foodForm" action="" method="POST">

<div class=".col-md-6">
<div id="scrollable-dropdown-menu">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Foods"> </div>
    <input type="button" class="submit_btn" value="ADD" name="add" onclick="functionAdd(); reset();" />
    <input type="button" class="submit_btn" value="DONE" name="done" onclick="functionDone()" />
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
  form=document.getElementById("foodForm");
  function functionAdd() {
      foodList.push(document.getElementsByName('search'));
      form.submit();
  }
  function functionDone() {
      form.action="submit_for_done.php";
      form.submit();
  }
```

The *functionAdd()* is not working. I want the function to add the search results from the form into the empty array (*foodList*). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your `functionAdd` function to find a value of `<input name="search">`:

```
<script>
    var foodList = [];
    function functionAdd () {
        var searchEl = document.getElementsByName('search')[0]; // input search element
        if (searchEl.value && searchEl.value.length > 0) { // exclude adding of empty values
            foodList.push(searchEl.value);
        }
        // form.submit(); // I think you don't need to submit the form every time you add new item to the food list
    }
    function functionDone() {
        document.write(foodList);
        form.action="submit_for_done.php";
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Irina, but when I try to show the contents of the array (_foodList_) using`document.write(foodList)`, the array is still empty. So it seems like the function still misses something.

Comment: @DreamWeaver, when and where are you trying to show the content of an array? could you please try to do `console.log(foodList)` and check browser's console if there're some values?

Comment: `var foodList=[]` is only declared at the beginning of the page, so before the _php form_. The `console.log(foodList)` returns this: `[].. length=0.. _proto_: array(0). Please tell me what you make out of it. Merci.

Comment: @DreamWeaver, here is the jsfiddle with my code https://jsfiddle.net/irinpotapova/dLjxamu7/19/

Comment: @DreamWeaver, I've updated jsfiddle, please try new link.

Comment: I tried out your improved code and it works. Now, the `console.log(foodList)` adds the searched item into _[0]_ location of the (_foodList_) array. I appreciate you.

Comment: But the current setting, only allows one searched item to be added into _[0]_ location. How can I make it in a way that each time the items are searched, they would saved in the array? i.e. the first item goes into _[0]_ location, the second searched item into _[1]_ and so on..

Comment: @DreamWeaver, current example do it this way. So, please remove `form.submit()` from `functionAdd` function and call it only at `functionDone` function. Hope it helps.

Comment: Irina, I tried what you said but it still only adds one item and upon _reset_, another item will be added to the _[0]_ location. Since this line `var searchEl = document.getElementsByName('search')[0]` specifies the _[0]_, that's why..

Comment: @DreamWeaver, `searchEl` is not a problem. You can easly add `id` to your `<input name="search">` and get this item like this: `var searchEl = document.getElementById("search")`. `document.getElementsByName("search")` returns an array and you should use the first item of this array, that's why `document.getElementsByName("search")[0]`.

Comment: @DreamWeaver, what is your test case? I see this test case: type something into the search field, click button `add`, type something, click `add`, etc. And then you click button `done`. Am I right?

Comment: @DreamWeaver, also please check if you're overriding `foodList = []` somewhere else.

Comment: Irina, the case would be like so: a user searches for an item and finds it. by pressing _ADD_, the item will be added to the array and the box will be reset. This could happen several times... until the items are finished and the user presses _DONE_.. by doing that, a list (which is the _listFood_array) will be shown to them.

Comment: @DreamWeaver, I can say jsfiddle I've provided you works properly. The main difference - there is no php code there and form doesn't submit. Please check your code and update it similar to the example. And please double check `foodList` declaration and each place where you're making changes for this array. Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay Irina, I got it. You were a great help. I appreciate it. Thanks again.